# how to solve audio encoding error in Media-translation GCP API?

Tags: node.js, windows, api, google-cloud-platform

Here's my code.
I have went through the google cloud platform API documentation, and followed as per the GCP DOC steps correctly. But still unable to fix the encoding error, which you can see it below. I'm trying to translate an audio clip from en-US(english) to hi-IN (hindi), and it would be helpful if you can give some alternative ways for this solution.

```
function main(filename, encoding, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage) {
 
  const fs = require('fs');

  const {
    SpeechTranslationServiceClient,
  } = require('@google-cloud/media-translation');

  const client = new SpeechTranslationServiceClient();

  async function quickstart() {
 
   const filename = './16kmonoceo.wav';
   const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
   const sourceLanguage = 'en-US';
   const targetLangauge = 'hi-IN';

    const config = {
      audioConfig: {
        audioEncoding: encoding,
        sourceLanguageCode: sourceLanguage,
        targetLanguageCode: targetLangauge,
      },
    };


    const initialRequest = {
      streamingConfig: config,
      audioContent: null,
    };

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
      highWaterMark: 4096,
      encoding: 'base64',
    });

    const chunks = [];
    readStream
      .on('data', chunk => {
        const request = {
          streamingConfig: config,
          audioContent: chunk.toString(),
        };
        chunks.push(request);
      })
      .on('close', () => {
        // Config-only request should be first in stream of requests
        stream.write(initialRequest);
        for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
          stream.write(chunks[i]);
        }
        stream.end();
      });

    const stream = client.streamingTranslateSpeech().on('data', response => {
      const {result} = response;
      if (result.textTranslationResult.isFinal) {
        console.log(
          `\nFinal translation: ${result.textTranslationResult.translation}`
        );
        console.log(`Final recognition result: ${result.recognitionResult}`);
      } else {
        console.log(
          `\nPartial translation: ${result.textTranslationResult.translation}`
        );
        console.log(`Partial recognition result: ${result.recognitionResult}`);
      }
    });

  }
  quickstart();
}

main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

here my error from command line.
[CHECK ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0S2I.png)
I'm using windows 10 and IDE VS CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where careful reading of the error message helps.

Some module gacked on "LINEAR16" as the audioEncoding value saying there's no encoding with that name.

A quick look at the [documentation shows "linear16"](https://cloud.google.com/translate/media/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.mediatranslation.v1beta1#translatespeechconfig) (lower case) as the value to use.

Comment: it worked but can you share some ways to get this output to save in local pc or gcp cloud using curl